# dash app refuse to connect while launching jupyter notebook container

Tags: python, docker, containers, plotly-dash

While trying to launch plotly dash from jupyter notebook container its showing the error like:

`The site cant be reached ' 10.*.*.*.* refused to connect.ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.`

I am running below codes..

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Its showing runnning on http://127.0.0.1:8050. But not launching on local host nor on 10.*.*.*:8050
I also `EXPOSE PORT 8050` in dockerfile for the connect.

Comment: Without docker your code is running fine. Probably there is an issue with the container. Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: It might be the problem that you are running dash app in jupyter notebook. Try to run it independent as a script.